# Query formatting for Parameterized Queries

Tags: postgresql, parameterized-query, pg-promise

I am using `pg-promise` to execute select query with like clause in PostgreSQL. Unfortunately the query is failing with error code as `08P01` and error message

> bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires
>   0

The query is as follows

```
select user_name, user_id from users where user_name like '$1#%'
```

I am using Parameterized query as

```
var userQuery:pgp.ParameterizedQuery = new pgp.ParameterizedQuery("<above_query>", [userName]);
```

The API used for executing query is

```
each(query:TQuery, values:any, cb:(row:any, index:number, data:Array<any>)=>void, thisArg?:any):XPromise<Array<any>>;
```

I looked at the pg-promise examples but it ain't using LIKE clause with Parameterized Query.

**Environment Details are**

> pg-promise: 4.3.2
>
> PostgreSQL: 9.6
>
> Node: 5.7.1

**UPDATE: 1**
I am able to run the query using `query` API (plain text sql) but not with `each`. Can anyone please explain why the LIKE clause is failing with `each` while using `Parameterized` API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [ParameterizedQuery API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html):

> Only the basic variables (`$1`, `$2`, etc) can be used in the query, because *Parameterized Queries* are formatted by the database server.

Types [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) and [ParameterizedQuery](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html) represent the corresponding objects within the [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) driver that executes them. Those objects encapsulate both the query and the formatting parameters.

i.e. the whole point of those two objects is to pass both query and the formatting parameters into the server, so they are formatted there, as opposed to using the internal query-formatting engine.

Because of that, you do not have access to the internal query-formatting features of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), such as `$1#` syntax. You can use the [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) syntax for query formatting when you are using queries directly, as a query string or as a [QueryFile](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html) object.

With [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) and [ParameterizedQuery](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html) you only have access to the basic `$1, $2,...` type of parameter formatting, as supported by the database server, nothing else.

---

P.S. I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t for responding to my question and providing link to the support documentation (upvoted for detailed description). What do you suggest in my scenario, where I wish to use like clause along with parameter? Is `query` API usage correct for the scenario or anything else is better.

Comment: You have [tons of examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example) to choose from.